# tweepy search giving more result than count parameter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy API to search tweets. My code looks like below

```
num_tweets=10
search = 'tesla stock'

num = 0

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+" -filter:retweets",count=num_tweets,lang="en").items():
    num +=1
    print(num)
    print(tweet.text)
```

The above code is not respecting the count parameter and keeps running until the application’s request rate limit is hit with below error

TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 429

Am I missing something?

Below is part of the result. See that the result count is a lot more:

```
1
We have 100 of the Tesla adapters in stock:  
2
@erikher101095 also PLEASE BUY TESLA STOCK!!
3
#Tesla $TSLA is the most exciting stock. but it’s not as 24/7 non-stop global exciting as crypto  #cryptotrifecta

....

1764
Love Tesla cars &amp; stock, but $7500+ rebates fueled Tesla growth &amp; Musk just kicked taxpayers firmly in the a**! 
1765
Tesla's Model 3 could reverse its stock slide #ElonMusk #ElonMusk 
1766
Tesla Inc (TSLA) Stock at Risk as Trump Exits Paris Accord
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the code like below, and it worked.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search+" -filter:retweets",lang="en").items(num_tweets):
```